# How can I write a php code for data can not find in table of MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

I am so sorry mybe it is a silly question but as I am new in web language and php I dont know how to solve this problem.

I have a code which is getting ID from user and then connecting to MySQL and get data of that ID number from database table and then show on webpage.

But I would like to what should I add to this code if user enter an ID which is not in table of database shows a message that no data found.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

//connect to the server
$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","Test","Test") ;

//connection to the database
mysql_select_db ("Test") ;

//query the database
$ID = $_GET['Textbox'];
$query = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM track WHERE Code = ('$ID') ");

//fetch the results / convert results into an array
$ID = $_GET['Textbox'];

WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) :

     $ID = 'ID';

  echo "<p style=\"font-color: #ff0000;\"> $ID </p>";


  endwhile;

?>
```

Thank You.

Sorry if it is so silly question.

Comment: Do not use depricated  `mysql_` api. Use `mysqli_` or `pdo`.

Comment: You should take a look at num_rows. First count the results in the query with num_rows. If it's zero, show an alert (or something), otherwise, show data from user. 

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: You should test if the query returned any result, if no, than there is no such an in id the database. Also, don't use mysql_ funtions, will be deprecated soon and NEVER, EVER insert user input to the query like this. Edit.: I think someone will explain it in an answer.

Comment: @appl3r I test and its working well all code. Let I explain like this.

it is like a tracking system. A user has one specific ID which contain some information such as statue of order on table in database.  when User enter the ID the information will be shown on webpage from database table.

But I want to add one php code if user enter wrong ID and it is not ID like this in  database table an error message shows.

Comment: I will write my answer as an answer, sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PDO (great tutorial here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers ). This way, you can develop safer applications easier. You need to prepare the ID before inserting it to the query string, to avoid any user manipulation of the mysql query (it is called sql injection, guide: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp ).

The main answer to your question, after getting the results, you check if there is any row in the result, if you got no result, then there is no such an ID in the database. If you use PDO statements `$stmt->rowCount();`.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Code=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // or  PDO::PARAM_STR
$stmt->execute();

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($row_count > 0) {
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //results are in $results
} else {
    // no result, no such an ID, return the error to the user here.
}
```

Another reason to not use mysql_* functions: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: If you have questions, fear not to ask.

Comment: Thank You its really nice answer but may I ask YOu please tell me where should I place your code in my php code?

Comment: You should replace you current code with this and also modify it, to match your preferences, like the database name, username, password, the query, and the `$id` variable (variable, name, string or integer).